# Criação de múltiplas linhas dinâmicas em uma tabela oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, tabela-banco-de-dados

Preciso criar uma nova tabela com múltiplas linhas utilizando dados de uma tabela anterior como parâmetro.

Por exemplo

```
_______________________
| nome   | quantidade |
|--------|------------|
| xyz    | 2          |
| abc    | 1          |
-----------------------
```

Esperado

```
__________________
| nome   | número|
|--------|-------|
| xyz    | 1     |
| xyz    | 2     |
| abc    | 1     |
------------------
```

No exemplo utilizo os dados de quantidade como parâmetro para criação de N linhas de acordo com a quantidade, e é populada na outra tabela com N linhas de quantidade e preenchendo a coluna número de 1 até N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN
  FOR R IN (SELECT NOME,QUANTIDADE FROM EXEMPLO)
  LOOP
    FOR I IN 1..R.QUANTIDADE
    LOOP
      INERT INTO TABELA (NOME,NUMERO) VALUES (R.NOME,I);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, criei uma stored procedure..muito obrigado pela ajuda !!!